# Can this product kill coronavirus?

Tags: covid-19, infection, virus, hygiene, coronavirus

I'm really really confused what product to buy to clean my laptop body to disinfect it from coronavirus.

Like most doctors say use 60-70% alcohol based sanitizers to clean your hands.

So does it mean only alcohol based things should be used to clean electronics like laptop and mouse bodies?

When searched a lot on Google, I found one product by Lysol [here](https://www.lysol.com/products/disinfecting-wipes/lysol-disinfecting-wipes-lemon-and-lime-blossom/). On this page it is not mentioned that it can kill coronavirus. But [here is something](https://www.businessinsider.com/epa-registered-cleaning-products?IR=T#purell-professional-surface-disinfectant-22) which makes me think that an Lysol wipes can be used to disinfect it from coronavirus virus. Lysol is listed there.

So can I use this product to disinfect it from coronavirus?

**One more query related to same:** I've always been afraid that cleaners that kills viruses can be bad for our personal health. For example, I'm not sure if we use hand sanitizer properly that kills 100% coronavirus, we should again wash our hands before eating? (Because this sanitizer might be toxic?)?

Same doubt is about Lysol. If I clean my mouse with it and it kills all the bacteria. And then I use my mouse and eat with same hands, can it be toxic and make me sick/dead?

Comment: Sounds like you're asking for personal computer advice

Comment: Lysol wipes contain benzalkonium chloride. It can be a skin irritant. Wash your hands after use and before eating. If you want maximum disinfection, you might leave the surface damp for several minutes; check the label. ❧ Even if you foolishly chew and swallow an entire Lysol wipe, you might vomit but are very unlikely to die. ❧ 70% rubbing alcohol solution (a liquid) will probably also work, and might be less likely to irritate your skin. For maximum disinfection, leave the surface damp for 30 seconds or more. ❧ Don't let any liquid or wipe solution reach a laptop's delicate motherboard.

Comment: Don't forget to disinfect your cellphone too.

Comment: I would not use Lysol on a laptop. Plain 70% isopropyl alcohol will do fine. Hand sanitizers are not toxic (unless you drink them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The EPA has a list of products known to be effective against COVID-19](https://www.epa.gov/pesticide-registration/list-n-disinfectants-use-against-sars-cov-2).  I can't tell you if your Lysol cleaner is one of them -- the list includes 14 different products sold under the Lysol brand, using five different active ingredients.

Any cleaning product should have instructions on how to use it safely.  As long as you follow those instructions, both you and the newly-cleaned object should be safe.

Comment: I forgot hyperlinks in my details. Updated now.